# Traversing DOM Tree

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on a JavaScript code for drag and drop box where user can basically drag images into a drop box and when they drag in a specific combination it returns some kind of a message.  For example if they drag in image1, image3, and image5 it returns a message.  I have been using DOM tree for this but I can't figure out how to check for when multiple images are dragged in.  I can get it to work when one image as shown bellow.  Any help would be appreciated as always.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset ="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        #dragBox {width:400px; height:320px; margin:10px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}

        .thumbnails img 
        {
            height: 80px;
            border: 4px solid #555;
            padding: 1px;
            margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
        }

        .thumbnails img:hover 
        {
            border: 4px solid #00ccff;
            cursor:pointer;
        }

    </style>
    <script>
    function allowDrop(ev)
    {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev)
    {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev)
    {
        ev.preventDefault();

        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        var theNode = document.getElementById(data);
        var nodeCopy = theNode.cloneNode(true);

        ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);

        if (data == "drag1")
        {
            foodOne();
        }

        //ev.target.removeChild(nodeCopy);

    }

    function foodOne()
    {
        alert("You choose Food One");
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#333333">
<div class="gallery" align="center">
    <div class="thumbnails">
        <img id="drag1" src="foodOne.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"">
        <img id="drag2" src="foodTwo.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >
        <img id="drag3" src="foodThree.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <img id="drag4" src="foodFour.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        </br></br>
        <div id="dragBox" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    </div></br>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not even sure something like multiple drops exists. But then again I haven't done much drag n drop stuff, maybe with multiples you get an event array ? Or some state saying something like outstanding drop operations left ?

So with my limited knowledge of this, To me the logical solution would be to have something like a result array where you push ids on each drop and then a new function to check if your array contains the combinations you are looking for.

Comment: I think he's doing the sequential (one by one) drag drop and needs to match the newly dropped element **and** the already dropped elements against some criterion